# How to merge Sql two sql query result display merge in one display

Tags: sql-server, merge

I want merge sql query result Side by side in one screen

Sample:

```
Barcode1    Barcode2
888            33
```

İt's possible ?

Thank you so much.

```
SELECT BARCODE AS BARCODE2  
FROM LG_001_UNITBARCODE, LG_001_ITEMS
WHERE ITEMREF = LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF 
  AND ITEMREF= 17 AND LINENR = 2;


SELECT BARCODE AS BARCODE3 
FROM LG_001_UNITBARCODE, LG_001_ITEMS 
WHERE ITEMREF = LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF 
  AND ITEMREF= 17 AND LINENR = 3;
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ You also really should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Will each subquery always only return 1 row?  if multiple rows does the order on which they relate matter?  'Full outer join and use a row_number() to window function to tie them together` would be one approach.

Comment: @xQbert: Perhaps `Cross Join` to combine all values of two queries :V

Comment: perhaps but I doubt they really want all values with all values that's why I asked;  I seldom see cross joins needed/used.

Comment: Wait for the OP's response .....

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a sub-select as below:

```
SELECT BARCODE AS BARCODE2 ,
        (
            SELECT BARCODE AS BARCODE3 
            FROM LG_001_UNITBARCODE, LG_001_ITEMS 
            WHERE ITEMREF = LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF 
                AND ITEMREF= 17 AND LINENR = 3
        ) as BARCODE3
FROM LG_001_UNITBARCODE, LG_001_ITEMS
WHERE ITEMREF = LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF 
AND ITEMREF= 17 AND LINENR = 2;
```

Comment: When subquery returns more than 1 result, then your query goes wrong.

Comment: Well, in the current case there's only one value returned. 
If there are more, that should have been specified as well as the way mrc user would want to handle it (as comma separated values or any other way..)
If there are more values returned from the sub-query, you are right, it needs to be handled differently :)

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that if multiple rows exist and different quantity of results for each table (one returns 3 records the other 5)  and that they should be related in barcode order from each table...
we can use 2 common table expressions and a row_number() analytic.  This way if multiple rows do exist, then they are all related based on the row number assigned and nulls will be present if one result set has more rows than the other.

However if it's a 1-1 this would still work.

```
WITH A as (SELECT BARCODE AS BARCODE2, row_number() over (order by barcode) RN 
           FROM LG_001_UNITBARCODE, LG_001_ITEMS
           WHERE ITEMREF = LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF 
             AND ITEMREF= 17 
             AND LINENR = 2),
     B as (SELECT BARCODE AS BARCODE3, row_number() over (order by barcode) RN 
           FROM LG_001_UNITBARCODE, LG_001_ITEMS 
           WHERE ITEMREF = LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF 
             AND ITEMREF= 17 
             AND LINENR = 3)

SELECT A.Barcode2, B.Barcode3 
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B 
 on A.RN = B.RN
;
```

Row_number() RN gives us a way to relate the tables in a barcode asc sequence.  the full outer join allows us to handle if one data set has more records than the other.